ROS2 Control Not Working with Gazebo and URDF
I am working on a project using ROS2 Humble and Gazebo, and I am facing an issue where the ROS2 control is not working as expected. Here are the details of my setup and the problem I am encountering:
ROS2 Distro: Humble
Gazebo Version: Gazebo 11
Hardware: Stepper motor controlled via Arduino
URDF File: Contains a prismatic joint and uses gazebo_ros2_control plugin
Controller Configuration: Includes joint state broadcaster and position controller
URDF File (test_cart_position.xacro.urdf):
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="cart">

  <!-- ROS2 Control Plugin -->
  <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
    <hardware>
      <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
    </hardware>
    <joint name="slider_to_cart">
      <command_interface name="position">
        <param name="min">-2.5</param>
        <param name="max">2.5</param>
      </command_interface>
      <state_interface name="position">
        <param name="initial_value">1.0</param>
      </state_interface>
      <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      <state_interface name="effort"/>
    </joint>
  </ros2_control>

  <!-- Prismatic Joint Definition -->
  <joint name="slider_to_cart" type="prismatic">
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
    <parent link="slideBar"/>
    <child link="cart"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-2.5" upper="2.5" velocity="30"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
  </joint>

</robot>


According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem with base class type hardware_interface::SystemInterface does not exist. Declared types are fake_components/GenericSystem mock_components/GenericSystem test_hardware_components/TestSystemCommandModes test_hardware_components/TestTwoJointSystem
Launch File (cart_control.launch.py):
import os
import xacro

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler, TimerAction
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessStart
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    # 패키지 이름 정의
    package_name = 'gazebo_ros2_control_demos'

    # URDF 파일 경로
    xacro_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name), 'urdf', 'test_cart_position.xacro.urdf')

    # URDF 파일 파싱 및 로딩
    doc = xacro.process_file(xacro_file)
    robot_description = {'robot_description': doc.toxml()}

    # Robot State Publisher 노드
    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[robot_description]
    )

    # 컨트롤러 매니저 노드
    controller_manager = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='ros2_control_node',
        parameters=[robot_description,
                    os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name), 'config', 'controllers.yaml')],
        output='screen'
    )

    # 컨트롤러 로드
    load_joint_state_broadcaster = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['joint_state_broadcaster', '--controller-manager', '/controller_manager'],
        output='screen'
    )

    load_position_controller = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['position_controller', '--controller-manager', '/controller_manager'],
        output='screen'
    )

    # Arduino 통신 노드 실행
    arduino_comm_node = Node(
        package='ros2_arduino_comm',
        executable='talker',
        name='arduino_comm_node',
        output='screen',
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        node_robot_state_publisher,
        TimerAction(period=3.0, actions=[controller_manager]),
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessStart(
                target_action=controller_manager,
                on_start=[load_joint_state_broadcaster],
            )
        ),
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessStart(
                target_action=load_joint_state_broadcaster,
                on_start=[load_position_controller],
            )
        ),
        arduino_comm_node,
    ])


What I've Tried:
Verified gazebo_ros2_control package is installed.
Checked controllers.yaml and URDF files for correct configuration.
Verified that the launch file correctly loads the robot description and controllers.
error log:
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/dev/.ros/log/2024-08-06-16-42-19-807446-dev-dev-12468
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [12469]
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722930139.902683320] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722930139.902758090] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_link_optical
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722930139.902766576] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment cart
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722930139.902771493] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment computer
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722930139.902776127] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment laser_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722930139.902780482] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment lidar
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722930139.902784831] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment slideBar
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722930139.902788996] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment support1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722930139.902793048] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment support2
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722930139.902797067] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment support3
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722930139.902800981] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment support4
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722930139.902804905] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment water_tank
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1722930139.902809051] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-3]: process started with pid [12491]
[INFO] [spawner-4]: process started with pid [12493]
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process started with pid [12495]
[ros2_control_node-3] [WARN] [1722930143.255055918] [controller_manager]: [Deprecated] Passing the robot description parameter directly to the control_manager node is deprecated. Use '~/robot_description' topic from 'robot_state_publisher' instead.
[ros2_control_node-3] [INFO] [1722930143.255281655] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'GazeboSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-3] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
[ros2_control_node-3]   what():  According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem with base class type hardware_interface::SystemInterface does not exist. Declared types are  fake_components/GenericSystem mock_components/GenericSystem test_hardware_components/TestSystemCommandModes test_hardware_components/TestTwoJointSystem
[ros2_control_node-3] Stack trace (most recent call last):
[ros2_control_node-3] #16   Object "", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #15   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x5d134f7e1d84, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #14   Source "../csu/libc-start.c", line 392, in __libc_start_main_impl [0x7f64be229e3f]
[ros2_control_node-3] #13   Source "../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h", line 58, in __libc_start_call_main [0x7f64be229d8f]
[ros2_control_node-3] #12   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x5d134f7e189e, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #11   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x7f64bebcce79, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::ControllerManager(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rclcpp::NodeOptions const&)
[ros2_control_node-3] #10   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x7f64bebc86bf, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::init_resource_manager(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
[ros2_control_node-3] #9    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7f64be5c0d9d, in hardware_interface::ResourceManager::load_urdf(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool)
[ros2_control_node-3] #8    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7f64be5bf1ce, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #7    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7f64be5a032a, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #6    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f64be6ae4d7, in __cxa_throw
[ros2_control_node-3] #5    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f64be6ae276, in std::terminate()
[ros2_control_node-3] #4    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f64be6ae20b, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #3    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f64be6a2b9d, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #2    Source "./stdlib/abort.c", line 79, in abort [0x7f64be2287f2]
[ros2_control_node-3] #1    Source "../sysdeps/posix/raise.c", line 26, in raise [0x7f64be242475]
[ros2_control_node-3] #0  | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 89, in __pthread_kill_internal
[ros2_control_node-3]     | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 78, in __pthread_kill_implementation
[ros2_control_node-3]       Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 44, in __pthread_kill [0x7f64be2969fc]
[ros2_control_node-3] Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 12491 1000)
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-3]: process has died [pid 12491, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_p_q49ynx --params-file /home/dev/ros2_ws/install/gazebo_ros2_control_demos/share/gazebo_ros2_control_demos/config/controllers.yaml'].
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1722930145.313640754] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1722930145.324437375] [spawner_position_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1722930147.341653039] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1722930147.352387749] [spawner_position_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1722930149.370987700] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1722930149.390733566] [spawner_position_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1722930151.400977121] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1722930151.426732626] [spawner_position_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-4] [ERROR] [1722930153.428113874] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-5] [ERROR] [1722930153.453752718] [spawner_position_controller]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-5]: process has died [pid 12495, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner position_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-4]: process has died [pid 12493, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args'].

```



Have you sourced your workspace? (source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash)
what does ros2 pkg xml -t version gazebo_ros2_control report?
have you run rosdep, e.g., rosdep install -riy --from-paths src?

